# API Rest Salesforce :Describe layouts does not return all layouts

Tags: api, rest

I just created a new org, so there are different layout on the Account object:

- Account Layout
- Account (Marketing) Layout
- Account (Sales) Layout
- Account (Support) Layout

But when I retrieve the describe from accounts using:

- /vXX.X/sobjects/Object/describe/layouts/

It returns only one layout:

[image]

Do you know why?

Thanks,

Regards,

MC

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the describe using REST request via Workbench and you are right; its not returning all the layouts.

Do you really need to use describe layout? I have managed to get the layout using Tooling API

Here is the syntax:

```
/services/data/v47.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+Id%2C+Name+FROM+Layout+WHERE+EntityDefinitionId+%3D+%27Account%27
```

Regards,
Raj